# How to make a platformer in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

(I am a new person in stackoverflow, might ask a bit different)

**How to make a platformer in Unity?**

*Unity 2020.2.0a11.1312.3*

> Info before start: I want to make a mobile game.
>
> (with some buttons)

Hello, I want to make a platformer in Unity.

I tried to use `Rigidbody2D.AddForce()` method but I couldn't get it working.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't usually work on mobile games in Unity but these are generally the reasons why rigidbodies don't work.

1. Make sure to connect the script to the object with the rigidbody by dragging the script on to the object.
2. Use `RigidBody2D Rigidbody2D = GetComponent<RigidBody2D>()` at the start of your script.
3. If you're using the `AddForce()` method in the `Start()` function then you need to move it to the `FixedUpdate()` function.
4. Sometimes the movement does work but it doesn't move the object very fast because there isn't enough force so you might have to increase the force.
5. Check to make sure that there are no movement constraints applied to the Rigidbody.
6. Since you're working with buttons you will have to link the buttons to the script with the rigidbody like:

```
    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        //Start moving logic
        moving = true
    }
    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        //Stop moving logic
        moving = false
    }

    private void FixedUpdate(){
      if(moving){
        //Moving
        Rigidbody2D.AddForce(force * Time.deltaTime)
      }else{
        //Not moving
      }
    }
```

Since OnPointerUp/Down is only called once when the event happens you need to put your start moving logic in `OnPointerDown` and stop moving the object in `OnPointerUp`.